# python failed to import smtplib

Tags: python, smtplib

I have a script as follow

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import smtplib
import datetime
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

now = '{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.datetime.now())

fromaddr = "xxx@gmail.com"
toaddr = "yyy@live.com"
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "Device Start Up Notification"

body = "Your device is started up %s " % now
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr, "abc12345")
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
server.quit()
```

When i execute this file, it shows error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./email.py", line 2, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 46, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "/home/jypang/email.py", line 4, in <module>
    from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
ImportError: No module named MIMEMultipart
```

The library is installed because I have another script which same as the script above (importing same library) and it's working well.

Please assist, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You named your module `email` which conflicts with standard library module `email`; `stmplib` module depends on the standard library module `email`.

You need to rename `email` with another name. If there's `email.pyc`, make sure delete it.

Comment: Thanks falsetru, lesson learned! Have to remove the email.pyc too